# ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object ejs-treegrid

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular application, I am unable to read from the service I created using [dataSource].

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getService' of undefined**

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RailroadAgreementService } from '../../services/railroad-agreement.service';
import { RRA_ID } from '../../models/RRA_ID';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-railroad-agreements',
  templateUrl: './railroad-agreements.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./railroad-agreements.component.css'],
})

export class RailroadAgreementsComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: RRA_ID[];

  constructor(private railroadAgreementService: RailroadAgreementService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.railroadAgreementService.getRRAId().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;
      console.log(this.data);
    })

  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<ejs-treegrid [dataSource]="data">

</ejs-treegrid>
```

Comment: Post your RailroadAgreementService and ejs-treegrid ts code

Comment: Try initializing the `data` array to an empty array to see if that removes the error. Like so: `public data: RRA_ID[] = [];`

Answer (score 1):

If the service method is returning a "cold" observable, it's value will initially be `null`, and your component is complaining that it can't access a property that it's expecting because it received `null` instead of an object, array, etc.

This is because the Observable code is running asynchronously.

To counter this, you can force the component to wait until the `data` property is truthy (not null, undefined, false an empty string, etc) to render:

```
<ejs-treegrid *ngIf="data" [dataSource]="data"></ejs-treegrid>
```